# Textfield with description right below the input box

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, textfield

I’m trying to recreate something like the below form. Essentially, a text input field with the description right below. Is this possible?

with borderstyle=U I can pretty much get the box to look similar with but not sure how to position text under it.

Also, when trying to print the resulting pdf without text, I would like it to print an empty line like the image below. Is that possible?

[image: example form field]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}`  and ending with `\end{document}`.